# Can't get PHP files to work "File not found"

Tags: centos, php, nginx, vps, fastcgi

I have nginx installed on my VPS which is running CentOS 6.3 and I can't seem to get any PHP files to work.

Here is my nginx.conf file:-

```
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  2;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


    events {
worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    server {
    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    listen 198.245.51.xxx;
    root /var/www/forum;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    access_log /var/log/virtualmin/example.org_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/virtualmin/example.org_error_log;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/forum/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/forum;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass           127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index          index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/forum/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/forum;
        include                 /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    }
    ssl_certificate /home/example/ssl.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/example/ssl.key;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
            autoindex on;
    }
    }
```

I get the following message whenever I try to open www.mydomain.com/index.php or any other php file:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6y7k.png

Thanks in advance! Please let me know if I can post anything else.

Comment: What's in /var/log/nginx/error.log & /var/log/virtualmin/example.org_error_log?

Comment: You have "fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME" set twice - once in the server block and once in the location block. This is usually set in the fastcgi_params file - which you also have included.

Comment: Wait - you also have both "include fastcgi_params;" and "include                 /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;" ?

Comment: And yeah - you should look in the error logs. Nginx should be returning a 502 error if the config was wrong. I am not sure what would output "File not found." It sounds like it may not be hitting nginx at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed user and group in domain.conf file and it started working again. It was set to User: Apache and Group: Apache by default.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem in the future! And thank you all for answering :)